# Sharing a reference to an instance of trait between threads

Tags: rust

I am playing with Rust's concurrency and trying to wrap my head around `Send`/`Sync`/`Arc`/`Mutex`. I have problems with sharing a reference to an instance of trait which is held in a `HashMap`:

```
use std::{collections::HashMap, sync::Arc, thread, time::Duration};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    foo: u8,
}

trait Foo {
    fn get_foo(&self) -> u8;
}

impl Foo for A {
    fn get_foo(&self) -> u8 {
        self.foo
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Arc::new(A { foo: 8 });

    let mut map: HashMap<u8, Arc<Foo>> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(8u8, a);

    for _ in 0..2 {
        let a = map.get(&8u8).expect("boom");
        let a = a.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let _ = a.get_foo();
        });
    }
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(200));
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=ed176d906fde27cfd890663a1dc1ab12))

It gives me these errors:

```
error[E0277]: `dyn Foo` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:27:9
   |
27 |         thread::spawn(move || {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `dyn Foo` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `dyn Foo`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Arc<dyn Foo>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:27:23: 29:10 a:std::sync::Arc<dyn Foo>]`
   = note: required by `std::thread::spawn`

error[E0277]: `dyn Foo` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:27:9
   |
27 |         thread::spawn(move || {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `dyn Foo` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `dyn Foo`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::sync::Arc<dyn Foo>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:27:23: 29:10 a:std::sync::Arc<dyn Foo>]`
   = note: required by `std::thread::spawn`
```

Could anyone please recommend an approach for this task? I think I'm kinda stuck with Rust's way to work with traits and threading.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remember that types of original values which are converted to trait objects are erased. Therefore, the compiler can't know whether the data inside the `Arc<Foo>` is `Send` and `Sync`, and without these traits sharing data across threads may be unsafe. You need to specify that types which can be stored in `Arc<Foo>` must be `Send` and `Sync`:

```
let mut map: HashMap<u8, Arc<Foo + Sync + Send>> = HashMap::new();
```

(try it [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=32864a09a88f1d141507a4ebb687b832))

The `Send` bound is required by `thread::spawn()`, and `Sync` is required by `Arc` for it to be `Send`. Additionally, `thread::spawn()` also requires `'static` but it is implicit in this particular `Arc<Foo + Sync + Send>` type declaration.

Of course, you will be able to store only `Sync` and `Send` implementations of `Foo`, but this is necessary to ensure memory safety. However, in Rust synchronization is implemented with wrappers like `Mutex<T>` or `RwLock<T>`. They don't implement `Foo` even if `T` implements `Foo`, therefore you won't be able to store, say, `Mutex<Foo + Send>` inside your map (unless `Foo` is your trait and you implemented it for `Mutex<Foo>`, which could be unwieldy), which would be necessary if your `Foo` implementations are not `Sync` but `Send` (though I'm not sure I can provide an example of such type now).

To solve this you'd need to change map type to contain a mutex inside it explicitly:

```
let mut map: HashMap<u8, Arc<Mutex<Foo + Send>>> = HashMap::new();
```

This way, there is no need for the `Sync` bound because `Mutex` is `Sync` if its contents are `Send`.

And naturally, you won't be able to share `Foo` implementations which are not `Send` at all, and there is no way around it. This can happen, for example, if `Foo`'s implementation contains `Rc`s.

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation. The only thing I'm missing - I don't understand why A is Send and Sync. I think I missed that somewhere in the book, but can't find it anymore. Could you please explain that point?

Comment: `A` is send and sync because it does not contain anything which is not `Send` or `Sync`. These traits are implemented automatically for all types which contain only `Send` and `Sync` members inside them, and your structure only contains a single primitive field which is `Send` and `Sync`.

Answer (score 15):

Vladimir gives one solution to your problem in the first half of his answer: tell Rust that your `HashMap` contains `Foo`s which are `Send` and `Sync`. Alternatively, you may change the definition of `Foo` itself to include these trait bounds:

```
trait Foo: Sync + Send {
    fn get_foo(&self) -> u8;
}
```

Since `struct A` is indeed `Send` and `Sync`, and since `struct A` does indeed implement `trait Foo`, the type checker will not complain when you use an `Arc<A>` as an `Arc<Foo>`.

If instead of sharing *immutable* (atomically reference counted) references to `Foo`s you wanted to share *mutable* (atomically reference counted) references to `Foo`s, you need to control access to the `Foo`s. This can be accomplished using e.g. a `Mutex`. Since the `Mutex` would then be taking care of the synchronization, the `Sync` bound on `Foo` can be dropped. For example:

```
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
    thread,
    time::Duration,
};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    foo: u8,
}

trait Foo: Send {
    fn get_foo(&self) -> u8;
}

impl Foo for A {
    fn get_foo(&self) -> u8 {
        self.foo
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(A { foo: 8 }));

    let mut map: HashMap<u8, Arc<Mutex<Foo>>> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(8u8, a);

    for _ in 0..2 {
        let a = map.get(&8u8).expect("boom").clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let result = a.lock().ok().expect("boom indeed").get_foo();
            println!("Result: {}", result);
        });
    }
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(200));
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=117a2f18dff8ab95b09c018e44ae1bf9))