# Specifying that a trait is Send and Sync in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, rust-tokio

I am writing a program that shares a trait between multiple threads. This is a contrived example:

```rust
pub trait A: Send + Sync {
    fn some_fun() {}
}

impl A for SomeStruct {
    fn some_fun() {
        // do something
    }
}

fn some_other_fun(object: Arc<dyn A>) {
    let object_copy = object.clone();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let _ = object_copy.get_foo();
    });
}
```

This works just fine because I tell the compiler that trait A is Send + Sync -- `pub trait A: Send + Sync`. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370021/sharing-a-reference-to-an-instance-of-trait-between-threads) other question I have to because

> types of original values which are converted to trait objects are erased.

so when `some_other_fun` takes in `object: Arc<dyn A>` it won't know the struct implementing this trait is Send and Sync unless the trait specified enforces it.

This interpretation seems logical to me, but I also found [this in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-04-extensible-concurrency-sync-and-send.html#implementing-send-and-sync-manually-is-unsafe)

> Because types that are made up of Send and Sync traits are automatically also Send and Sync, we don’t have to implement those traits manually. As marker traits, they don’t even have any methods to implement. They’re just useful for enforcing invariants related to concurrency.

I believe my example above is still fine because I am actually specifying that a trait is Send and Sync, and not implementing the Send and Sync on a type. Is that right? If so I think it might be useful to state that a bit more clearly in the documentation.

Comment: Not sure where the confusion is. The last quote is simply saying that you don't need `impl Send for SomeStruct {}` explicitly; the compiler will provide that automatically (if its contents are `Send` of course). That is unrelated to supertraits.

Comment: What do you mean by "still fine"? In any case, the point of the `Send` and `Sync` traits is that your code will not compile if it's wrong. This code (when fixed) compiles, so it's fine. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=102adfa1740854c5b612e2ee05d8ef00

Comment: When i read the documentation I interpret it as "you don't need to specify that things are Send and Sync because rust should be able to infer it", which is not true if you are using dynamic traits to specify the type of a property -- rust won't be able to know if that property is Send + Sync and you'll have to manually specify it in the Trait. That was my wrong initial interpretation

Comment: Note that another option is to not list `Send` and `Sync` as supertraits, and instead add them only when needed, e.g. as `Arc<dyn A + Send + Sync>`.

Comment: oh, that's cool. So i don't force every implementer of trait A to be thread safe.

Comment: @drewtato i actually realize that the confusion i had here is in distinguishing between "marking" something with a trait, and "implementing" the trait. The doc is saying not to "implement" those traits, but to use them as "markers"

Comment: The term "marker trait" is just used to describe traits that don't have any associated methods or types - hence they simply "mark" that an implementer has such property.

Comment: In rust, a *marker trait* is a trait that has no actual functionality. `Send`, `Sync`, and `Eq` are all marker traits. In that sense, marking is implementing. An *auto trait* is special in that it's implemented for every applicable type unless manually removed. However, neither of those applies here. The only things that are happening is you're creating a *subtrait* of `Send`/`Sync` and you're adding *trait bounds* on the `dyn A` by adding `+ Send + Sync`.

Comment: *Traits* are not *types* and the auto implementation only applies to types. Traits are *constraints* and thus when you define a dynamic trait object `dyn A`, it can be any underlying type that satisfies the constraints. If `A` didn't require `Send` and `Sync`, then `dyn A` is not thread-safe because non-thread-safe types can implement `A`. Only with the `trait A: Send + Sync` or `dyn A + Send + Sync` is the dynamic object constrained that it must also be thread-safe.